# Regex to identify decimal between 0.0 and 1.0

Tags: asp.net, regex, c#-4.0

Im looking for a regex validation expression to validate if a decimal value (x) is as follows:
0.0<=x<=1.0

Only one decimal place is allowed. How do I do it?

Thanks

Comment: Why use regex? Surely parsing to a `decimal` and testing directly is better?

Comment: Hi @Oded, I want to validate the data fields on client side before calling the server so i reduce server interaction

Comment: What kind of client? If this is JavaScript, why tag it with C#? The regex engines are similar, but not the same.

Comment: @Oded Its an asp.net page. I'm using the <asp:RegularExpressionValidator> to validate the textbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this it will check one decimal place instead of other proposed variants

```
^((0\.[0-9]{1})|(1\.0))$
```

Comment: The quantifier is not needed, you took my answer and added redundancy, nice.

Answer (score 3):

The regexp would be:

```
^(:?(:?0\.[0-9])|(:?1\.0))$
```

But why not use decimal comparison?

Comment: Surely ^(:?(:?0\.[0-9]{1})|(:?1\.0))$ - i.e {1} rather than + as only 1dp is allowed.

Comment: @BunjiquoBianco `0.0 < 0.5545 < 1.0` holds.

Comment: agreed on your logic, but this would allow 0.5545 as a valid entry and OP says it wouldn't be - "Only one decimal place is allowed"

Comment: @BunjiquoBianco don't know how I skipped over that, thanks for pointing it out *(fixed)*

Comment: @BunjiquoBianco You don't need the quantifier, `[0-9]` as is counts for only one digit, but instead of `[0-9]` you could use `\d` anyway (still no quantifier needed).

Comment: Yeah, true! sudo_O has opted for that in his answer so we're all good.